# ¿Por qué decimos "sombrero EN paja" en lugar de "DE"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, ropa

Quisiera saber por qué se dice:

> Sombrero **EN** paja trenzada con cinta de grosgrain alrededor de la copa.
> <sub>[fuente](https://www2.hm.com/es_es/productpage.0503657001.html)</sub>

En vez de:

> Sombrero **DE** paja trenzada con cinta de grosgrain alrededor de la copa.

O sea, ¿qué significa “EN” en este contexto?

Comment: Eso viene **del francés**: une robe en soie [un vestido de seda]. El tejido de una ropa o el material de una ropa es EN: en soie, en coton, en lin, etc. Es esnobismo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La frase "**en** X material" se suele oír en desfiles de moda como un modo de realzar el material.

En efecto, "sombrero en paja trenzada" suena un poco más sofisticado que "sombrero de paja trenzada".

En ambos casos, el término "paja trenzada" indica el material del cual está hecho el artículo, pero "en" se entiende derivado de: *sombrero realizado en paja trenzada*, como si el sombrero fuera una obra de arte más que un accesorio de vestir.

- Hoy María luce un vestido **en** seda natural en los tonos del azul y un sombrero **en** paja trenzada en la gama del tostado. (Equivalente a: un vestido DE seda natural azul ... un sombrero DE paja trenzada tostado)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con la respuesta de @Gustavson. Solo quiero aclarar que en el lenguaje del día a día no se usa "EN" sino "DE". "EN" es como algo más poético.

Comment: Creo que quisiste decir que "EN" es algo más poético.

Comment: Sí, gracias @Gustavson. He actualizado mi respuesta.